# Airflow HiveOperator not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, hive, airflow

I am trying to use a hive operator in airflow. I have all the dependencies installed (pyhs2, pyhive, and ran pip install airflow[hive]).

However when I use the code below

```
t1 = HiveOperator(
    task_id='simple_query',
    hql='select * from cities',
    dag=dag)
```

I get this error. I am not sure what it means

```
[2016-01-06 03:26:39,500] {models.py:1017} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 977, in run
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/operators/hive_operator.py", line 65, in execute
    self.hook.run_cli(hql=self.hql, schema=self.schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py", line 110, in run_cli
    cwd=tmp_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[2016-01-06 03:26:39,512] {models.py:1053} ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs when the `hive` command line interface (CLI) isn't available in your system path.

Comment: +1. This is the issue. Or you are missing beeline if you are have the "use_beeline" extra param set to true